# Extracting values for transactions in website response using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

When i hit an application by using Python i am getting below response, Can someone please help me to extract the transaction values using Python, Please find Sample website response below...

```
{"results":[{"statement_id":0,"series":[{"name":"gatling","tags":{"script":"sc01_AddToBasket"},"columns":["time","sum"],"values":[[1537489800000,5]]},{"name":"gatling","tags":{"script":"sc01_ClickFourthWeekSlotDelivery"},"columns":["time","sum"],"values":[[1537489800000,10]]},{"name":"gatling","tags":{"script":"sc01_ClickFourthWeekSlotDelivery_4Hr"},"columns":["time","sum"],"values":[[1537489800000,0]]},{"name":"gatling","tags":{"script":"sc01_ClickHomeDelivery"},"columns":["time","sum"],"values":[[1537489800000,3]]}]}]}

Sample expected output:

Transaction name                     Count
sc01_AddToBasket                      5
sc01_ClickFourthWeekSlotDelivery      10
sc01_ClickFourthWeekSlotDelivery_4Hr  0
sc01_ClickHomeDelivery                3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read in the json then parse:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

jsonStr = '{"results":[{"statement_id":0,"series":[{"name":"gatling","tags":{"script":"sc01_AddToBasket"},"columns":["time","sum"],"values":[[1537489800000,5]]},{"name":"gatling","tags":{"script":"sc01_ClickFourthWeekSlotDelivery"},"columns":["time","sum"],"values":[[1537489800000,10]]},{"name":"gatling","tags":{"script":"sc01_ClickFourthWeekSlotDelivery_4Hr"},"columns":["time","sum"],"values":[[1537489800000,0]]},{"name":"gatling","tags":{"script":"sc01_ClickHomeDelivery"},"columns":["time","sum"],"values":[[1537489800000,3]]}]}]}'

jsonObj = json.loads(jsonStr)

parse = jsonObj['results'][0]['series']

results_df = pd.DataFrame()
for each in parse:
    alpha = each['tags']['script']
    count = each['values'][0][1]

    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[alpha, count]], columns = ['Transaction name','Count'])

    results_df = results_df.append(temp_df)

results_df = results_df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
print (results_df)
                       Transaction name  Count
0                      sc01_AddToBasket    5
1      sc01_ClickFourthWeekSlotDelivery   10
2  sc01_ClickFourthWeekSlotDelivery_4Hr    0
3                sc01_ClickHomeDelivery    3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, implemented above and got the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

In loop create list of tuples and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
import json

d = json.loads(j)

out = []
for x in d['results']:
    for y in x['series']:
        out.append((y['tags']['script'], y['values'][0][1]))
```

List comprehension alternative:

```
out = [(y['tags']['script'], y['values'][0][1]) for x in d['results'] for y in x['series']]
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(out, columns = ['Transaction name','Count'])
print (df)
                       Transaction name  Count
0                      sc01_AddToBasket      5
1      sc01_ClickFourthWeekSlotDelivery     10
2  sc01_ClickFourthWeekSlotDelivery_4Hr      0
3                sc01_ClickHomeDelivery      3
```